# Linux equivalent to RDP and TS Gateway

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, terminal-server, x11

Windows, TS and TS Gateway: A wonderful combination for remote working.

How can you deliver a similar user experience with Linux as the server side platform? Ideally the clients would be Windows, but could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the local network, X11 is the tried and true method for this and is in use far longer than any similar Windows service.

Simplest form is with SSH port forwarding (`ssh -X`), but you can export a full desktop with XDMCP on the local network (potentially not very secure anymore).

Over a WAN, network latency will often be too high to make plain X11 usable, but then you can use the compressed NX system, which is available both as a commercial (free for some use-cases) implementation from [Nomachine.com](http://nomachine.com) and as free alternative implementations where I don't know the current status.

Answer (score 0):

VNC works well and has windows client. You may adjust it to your bandwidth.